# Correct REST-ful way to create/update multiple objects of the same resource in a single request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I have iOS application working against Rails application. Let's say I have TeamMember model and on iOS application I need to create/update multiple team members using single request (in transactional manner - all should be saved or fail altogether if something went wrong).

Example: is it ok to send POST /team_members with body:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Tom"
    },
    {
        "name": "Derek"
    }
    ...
]
```

?

What confuses me is that my theoretical JSON example has array instead of single-record hash which is usual when posting single team member record for POST /team_member. The same goes for PUT /team_members request.

I would be very thankful to anyone who could explain to me how or is it ever possible to accomplish this in RESTful manner?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be possible, but your service contract has to be defined in terms of arrays.

You service will determine if it is valid or not and should handle it being transactional.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do know it is technically possible to be defined in terms of arrays. This question is more likely about RESTful way of accomplishing this.

Comment: As long as you have some ids in your array elements, I think this can be just as restful as getting arrays.

Answer (score 0):

routes.rb

```
resources :team_member_batches
```

controller

```
class TeamMemberBatchesController < ApplicationController

    def create
        t = TeamMemberBatch.new(team_member_attributes: JSON.parse(params[:team_member_attributes]))
        if t.save
          # All good
        else
          # Something went wrong...
        end
    end
end
```

model (well not really a model but ok)

```
class TeamMemberBatch

  attr_accessor :team_members

  def initialize(atts)
    self.team_members = []

    atts.each do |team_member_attributes|
      self.team_members << TeamMember.new(team_member_attributes)
    end
  end

  def save
    unless team_members.all.map(&:valid?).uniq.include?(false)
       team_members.all.map(&:save)
       true
    end

    false
  end
end
```

Comment: Marcello, thanks for the answer. I also thought about implementing it this way. However what stops me from starting doing it is that I imagine that if on a real project I have something like 30-50 real resources having +5-10 more of such intermediate resources (which do not point to real resources) the project will become a mess? Do you really organize your batch resource request this way in your real projects?

Comment: Also, while this solution __seems__ to be RESTful I am actually not sure if it is semantically correct to create such intermediate resources just for the purpose of creating batch records in one request. What do you think?

Comment: I dont remember having to do that in batches where the elements didnt really have a parent object. But no - you dont need to create one for each class. You could have one single ResourceBatch class, and one resources :resource_batches in your routes. And make it smart enough to instantiate and save the classes as you'd need them. I can update the answer to reflect that if you'd like to see it.

Comment: Yes, I understand. No need in example. I am still not sure if this is a good idea from design perspective. As for me umbrella resource for batches looks like a bad idea for large projects.